# how do I access a server inside a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine

I setup virtualbox running debian for website development inside of Windows 7. Can I access that webserver running inside the VM from Windows 7? I tried going to 127.0.0.1 and FF said there's no server, so it looks like it's not running automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the VM in bridged mode for networking, then you can treat it like any other computer on your network. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback for your host machine, not the VM. You will need to go to the unique IP of the VM.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the "loopback" address that will access a server on the same machine.  That is, an application on your Windows 7 host could access a DB server on the Windows 7 host by that address.  Or an application running on the Debian guest could access a DB server running on the Debian guest using that IP address.  You need the app to connect to the DB on a different machine so the loopback connection isn't going to work.

If you're going from the Windows 7 host to the Debian guest VM then you are for all intents and purposes connecting to a different machine, so you need to specify whatever IP address the Debian guest has been assigned on your network.

Step 1:  First make sure that the Debian guest is in fact connecting to the network properly, which is what MarkM suggested in his post about putting the VM in bridged mode for networking.

Step 2:  Once you've confirmed that the Debian guest is properly connecting to the network, find out what IP address is assigned to it.  To get this you can run the appropriate utility on debian command line (ifconfig) and find the ip address assigned, which will probably be something like 192.168.x.x.  That's the address you can then use to connect to the DB server running on the Debian VM.